# get the id of the newly created subsite (web) programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Suppose I have two buttons: one that created a subsite and the other that gets the id of the newly created subsite and inserts it into a webpart's properties.

Qustion 1: How can I get the ID of the newly created subsite programmatically?

Qustion 2: How can I insert the ID of the new subsite into a webpart that exists already?

Any code or reference is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try using an event receiver.

Suppose say, you want to something done on the creation of a site being provisioned. You can add an `event receiver` item and select something like `A web was provisioned`.

And in your code this can go in for getting the web ID -

```
public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.WebProvisioned(properties);
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("your url goes in here"))
        {
            SPWeb web = properties.Web; // this will get you the properties for the newly created site
            //using (SPWeb w = web)
            //{
                Guid webID = w.ID;
            //}
        }
    }
```

Hope this gives you some sort of reference and help you in reaching somewhere with part 2 of your query too.

Comment: Hi Sane.Amit, your answer points me in the right direction. Now I have to handle part two.